# How to use a sub-query as value for inserting?

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1,col2,col4)
            VALUES (1, (select col1 from table2 where col2 = :param), 1);
```

The above query works as well. Now I want to use two columns from `table2`, like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1,col2,col3,col4)
            VALUES (1, (select col1,col2 from table2 where col2 = :param), 1);
```

But second query doesn't work, How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2, col3, col4)
select 1, col1, col2, 1 
from table2 
where col2 = :param;
```